# operator -> not working for custom input iterator

Tags: c++

I have a complex data structure for which I want to define an input iterator. I want to avoid modifying the content through the iterator so `operator*` should return a `const` reference.

The problem is that when I try to use `->` on the iterator with a `const` method I get an error:

> base operand of `->` has non-pointer type `MyInputIterator`

Here is a minimal example:

```
// this is supposed to be a much more complex data structure
std::vector<std::string> a = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"};

class MyInputIterator : std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, std::string>
{
public:
    MyInputIterator(int i = 0)
    {
        j = min(i, a.size());
    }

    MyInputIterator& operator++()
    {
        j = min(j + 1, a.size());
        return *this;
    }

    const std::string& operator*() const
    {
        return a[j];
    }

    ...

private:
    int j;
};

int main()
{
    MyInputIterator it(0);
    // error: base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'MyInputIterator'
    std::cout << it->size() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might consider *defining* that operator if you expect it to work.

Comment: `it` is not pointer, you can't call `operator->` and it has no `size()` member function.

Comment: @WhozCraig I have seen examples where it wasn't defined and there was no error. I'm not sure whether it is possible in my case.

Comment: @billz `it` doesn't have to be a pointer for it to be called `operator->()` upon. size() is a member function of `std::string` which is the `value_type` of `MyIterator`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add this to your iterator

```
const std::string* operator->() const
{
    return &a[j];
}
```

Now your `main` will work

Answer (score 1):

In order to call `operator->()` on your `MyInputIterator` class you must first implement it.

In your case it would look something like:

```
const std::string* operator->() const 
{
    return &a[j];
}
```